# Wordpress website Spam/Hacked, Mailout.php

Tags: wordpress, spam

My domain has been suspended by my host because they have detected spam.
They say that the file "mailout.php" has been used to send out spam mails.
The file is found here:

```
/public_html/wp-content/themes/[My_theme]/mailout.php
```

My host tells me to either delete the file or "protect its functions". So my question is.

1. Can I delete this file? My site does send out mails after a costumer has placed an order through woocommerce.
2. What do they mean by "protect its functions"? How do I do that?

I look forward to hear from you! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Propably your website was infected by injecting malicious code.
On your server you need find weird files like xyz.php folder with different name than wordpress files and folders.
The best will be change script for send emails and use smtp options not sending by php.
When you need more help I can check that for you but without see problem I can only recommend searching the files at an angle of strange file names and of course delete this wierd files.
First check if mailout.php is normal file from your theme.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Robort. Do I look under my theme or just everywhere on the server? I have been looking but cant find any wierd.